# Android View.requestRectangleOnScreen: Scroll-error in API-23! How, do I work around it?

Tags: android, android-layout, focus

I am developing my first Android App and after a good start, I have spent days of deep debugging on a problem, which by now seems to be an error in the implementation of `View.requestRectangleOnScreen` in API-23 and probably many levels before that.  Just now, I have discovered that the implementation of this routine is changed significantly in API-25.

The problem is that a request for focus on an EditText placed inside a HorizontalScrollView may cause the HorizontalScrollView to scroll away from the field requesting the focus.
In my case it is an EditText with centered text, which is then placed in the center of 1048576 pixels and scrolled roughly half a million pixels to the right making the text centered and visible (this part is perfectly ok!) But then this offset of half a million pixels is propagated up the parent chain and makes the HorizontalScrollView move to its far right and far away from the input field.

I have tracked it down to the View.requestRectangleOnScreen routine, which in the API-23 sources is as follows:

```
public boolean requestRectangleOnScreen(Rect rectangle, boolean immediate) {
    if (mParent == null) {
        return false;
    }

    View child = this;

    RectF position = (mAttachInfo != null) ? mAttachInfo.mTmpTransformRect : new RectF();
    position.set(rectangle);

    ViewParent parent = mParent;
    boolean scrolled = false;
    while (parent != null) {
        rectangle.set((int) position.left, (int) position.top,
                (int) position.right, (int) position.bottom);

        scrolled |= parent.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(child,
                rectangle, immediate);

        if (!child.hasIdentityMatrix()) {
            child.getMatrix().mapRect(position);
        }

        position.offset(child.mLeft, child.mTop);

        if (!(parent instanceof View)) {
            break;
        }

        View parentView = (View) parent;

        position.offset(-parentView.getScrollX(), -parentView.getScrollY());

        child = parentView;
        parent = child.getParent();
    }

    return scrolled;
}
```

The idea is to make the `rectangle` visible by scrolling it onto the screen in every containing View, starting at the leaf level and passing the request up the chain of parents.  The initial `rectangle` is given in child coordinates, which of course have to be adjusted as we work our way up the chain of parents.  This is done with the statement

```
position.offset(-parentView.getScrollX(), -parentView.getScrollY());
```

close to the end of the code above.

What I have found, is that this is wrong because we are transforming the `position` given in child coordinates using the scroll X/Y values pertaining to the parent coordinates.  Using the scroll X/Y of the child instead solved my problem but it was not possible to make a perfect override of this routine because it relies on private member variables.  Specifically, I found no way of mimicing the `mAttachInfo`.

Now, digging a bit further, I found that the code for this routine in API-25 has changed significantly and (IMHO) correctly to the following:

```
public boolean requestRectangleOnScreen(Rect rectangle, boolean immediate) {
    if (mParent == null) {
        return false;
    }

    View child = this;

    RectF position = (mAttachInfo != null) ? mAttachInfo.mTmpTransformRect : new RectF();
    position.set(rectangle);

    ViewParent parent = mParent;
    boolean scrolled = false;
    while (parent != null) {
        rectangle.set((int) position.left, (int) position.top,
                (int) position.right, (int) position.bottom);

        scrolled |= parent.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(child, rectangle, immediate);

        if (!(parent instanceof View)) {
            break;
        }

        // move it from child's content coordinate space to parent's content coordinate space
        position.offset(child.mLeft - child.getScrollX(), child.mTop -child.getScrollY());

        child = (View) parent;
        parent = child.getParent();
    }

    return scrolled;
}
```

The most important change being the line

```
position.offset(child.mLeft - child.getScrollX(), child.mTop -child.getScrollY());
```

where the scroll X/Y adjustment is now made with child values.

Now, I have two questions.

First, do you agree with my observations above?

Second, how do I implement an App that can be used on both API-23 and API-25 under the given circumstances?

My current thoughts are to sub class the EditText and override the `requestRectangleOnScreen` method such that when the API is 25 and above, it just calls the super class method and when the API is below 25, I basically do a full override using code along the lines of the code from API-25 but then missing out on the `mAttachInfo` part.